# Append Elements to Expanding List

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to generate an expanding nested list. How do I generate a nested list as such?

```
[1.0, None]
[-1.0, [1.0, None]]
[-1.0, [1.0, [3.0, None]]]
[6,[-1.0, [1.0, [3.0, None]]]]
```

Essentially, I want to create a nested list in which each element gets inserted into the original list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you create a class for this functionality. A template you could work with would be:

```
class nestlist:
    def __init__(self,startlist=[]):
        self.nestlist=startlist
    def get(self):
        return self.nestlist
    def add(self,x):
        self.nestlist = [x,self.nestlist]
    def pop(self):
        popval = self.nestlist[0]
        self.nestlist = self.nestlist[1]
        return popval

nl = nestlist()
nl.add(1)
nl.add(-1)
nl.add(6)

print(nl.get())
```

This creates the class, and adds 1, -1, and 6 as per your example. When get() is called, it returns [6,[-1,[1,[]]]] as required. I also added a analogous "pop" function to demonstrate how using a class could be beneficial when expanding this idea.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are appending the new element to the first of the list and making the previous one a sublist:

```
l = [1.0, None]
new = [-1.0]
new.append(l)
```

Then, `new` will be:

```
[-1.0, [1.0, None]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do something like that:

```
import random

l = [-1.0, None]

for i in range(10):        
    l = [random.randint(0, 10), l]

print(l)
```

You just wrap the original list into another list.